# Licensing : .NET + NHibernate / MySQL / MSSQL / PostgreSQL /

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, licensing

I am studying possibilities for a project for my company and after many considerations, I'm investigating building the application on NHibernate for object mapping, which would allow our customers to use whatever database management system they'd prefer or are used too, etc... be it MySQL, MSSQL, PostgreSQL or even SQLite in case of little amounts of data. Some our customers have various database systems already in place.

My concern is about licensing around these database management systems, in respect to how we plan to develop the application. For example, MySQL is GPL and MSSQL proprietary. Of course, I would not distribute the related connectors all in the final solution but, instead, let the customer choose its own and install the relevant connectors and database server...

- In this case, would we need to buy licenses for all those connectors and systems (which would represent a lot of money I guess) ?
- Or should our customer buy a license for the database system of its choice ?
- Or can we just ship the application without any database related file and let the customer do its business ?

Thanks for the help,
Pierre.

Comment: I don't understand the -1 to my question. Is there something wrong or incorrect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm **not a lawyer**, but:

1. Only if the adapter is used (e.g for testing) or supplied/distributed. Contact the DB vendor for the the applicable usage and distribution rules.
2. If it is the customers responsibility to do so, then yes: the adapters may be provided by the DB vendor or by a 3rd party (commercial or otherwise). Contact the DB vendor for information on obtaining and using said adapters (so that this information can be distributed to customers). *Let the customer handle any database licensing.*
3. Yes. See the above two points.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks. It seems indeed safer to let the customer deal with possible database concerns and integration. I guess that designing an application for _possible / optional_ use with various database systems does not require buying a license.

Comment: Hi again, I could get an answer from a MySQL guy that first tried to tell I was trying to get around the licensing issue, though I'm not particularly interrested in MySQL, but instead wishing to let the customer use whatever database he would prefer and deal with it independantly. Then, after explaining what my application was doing with NHibernate the possibility for multiple DBs, he told me he "thought" that if I were not redistributing any MySQL component, I would not be subject to any license. IANAL too but I think I'm in the right not paying if not redistributing anything MySQL.